# RPWrap v1.6.2 is not working after many installation attemps

Tags: rdp

i have a critical issue with my **Windows 10 Enterprise Insider Preview - Build 21301.1010**  where i,m trying to deploy the RDP-Wrapper latest version **v1.6.2**(the one i use based on the latest release [rdpwRAP v1.6.2](https://github.com/SobieskiCodes/RDPWrap)), but unsuccesfully. I have run a clean install, but it does not seems to help  at all.

Following are my errors list:

[image: RDPWrap-not-working-at-all-windows-10-enterprise-preview]
[image: RDPWrap-not-working-at-all-windows-10-enterprise-preview-Configuration]

I also created an issue here on official page [RDP Wrapper v1.6.2 don,t work on Windows 10 Enterprise Insider Preview - Build 21301.1010 ?](https://github.com/stascorp/rdpwrap/issues/1499)

Comment: you need an updater for RDP Wrapper, Please follow with the Official Page, they will respond to you

Comment: @MohammadRezamoeini what do you mean with updater ?

Comment: @MohammadRezamoeini As you can see in the folder structure, there are everything supposed to be needed !

Comment: it seems related to the library based on windows build  for example  : https://github.com/stascorp/rdpwrap/issues/851

Comment: @MohammadRezamoeini i will give those others propositions a try and come back to you

Comment: @MohammadRezamoeini Those proposition with clean install of rdp wrapper do not work either

Comment: Did you change rdpwrap.ini , first a getback up from that file in program files and then replace it with file https://raw.githubusercontent.com/asmtron/rdpwrap/master/res/rdpwrap.ini

Comment: Yes i did all steps as needed, as i mentioned it,s not my first installation try! install, override rdpwrap.ini,  restart computer, etc...

Comment: RDP Wrapper is a violation of the EULA. Stop using it.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because doing this is a violation of the EULA.

Comment: @joeqwerty, why this is only experimental, i don,t understand your point!

Comment: It's a violation of the EULA. Therefore it's illegal. It doesn't matter what your rationalization is. If I rob a bank and tell the police that I was only experimenting does that absolve me of the crime?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So i had to install a windows 10 pro build **20hX** for this experimental purpose and it does work now:

[image: Tested]